# ssh tunnel for websocket

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

I have a websocket service at remote server port 4444:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name                      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:4444          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
```

I am trying to tunnel from my localhost port 5555:

```
ssh -N -L 5555:localhost:4444 remote-server
```

It does not seem to be working. Does it look right? Am I using the right flag? Thanks.

Comment: You're trying to tunnel *from* localhost:5555. Yes?

Comment: Could you please let us know if there is any firewall running on your local machine? Its possible that the service is exposing a port but your firewall is blocking all incoming connections.

Comment: Yeah. It was my setup. My bad. Thank you!